# Google iframe issue in webkit webview it working fine

Tags: swift, google-maps

I used this code in WebKit ios 11.2 where my google map frame not showing to fit to screen it showing like this I attached the screenshot.

```
let topBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height +
            (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0)
        webView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: topBarHeight + 20, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - topBarHeight)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false

  webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><iframe width=\"\(self.webView.frame.size.width)\" height=\"\(self.webView.frame.size.height-70)\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\" src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=\(GoogleApikey)&q=\(Company.Instance.shopAddress),\(Company.Instance.shopName)\"allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

[image: this is the screenshot of webkit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraints aren't fully set in `viewDidLoad()`. you should move your code in other life cycle methods like `viewDidAppear()` and use the following HTML String for loading it

```
webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><iframe frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0;width: 100%;height:100%\" src=\"https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=\(GoogleApikey)&q=\(Company.Instance.shopAddress),\(Company.Instance.shopName)\"allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you add your map?

You could try to add it inside function viewDidLoad. For example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: topBarHeight + 20, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - topBarHeight)
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    webView.scrollView.bounces = false
}
```

And you use it `self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true`, but navigation bar is not hidden. Did you implement custom navigation bar and hide native bar? Or it does not have to be visible?

Comment: What is the issue?

You tried to add web view when view was not loaded, so it did not have full screen frame.

Comment: Okay.

Why do you not use Google Maps SDK for that? I see you are trying to add maps using HTML code. Google Maps have a good documentation for that - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro

May be I don't know something and this way is not good for you.